# Can I use both “of”and “‘s” to show possession for people?

Tags: possessives

I have just read from the Cambridge *Essential Grammar in Use* series that for people we normally use “‘s” to show possession and “of” for things, but I have been using both “‘s” and “of” for both people and things all the time.

I used to use “of” for people when writing Uni essay as my professor told me not to use “‘s” in academic essay so I just thought that “of” is more formal?

I also read from another related question’s answer that for a simple noun, just use “‘s”, and for a complicated noun like “the tee shirt of the man that I met at work“, use “of” instead. So what is the correct usage of “‘s” and “of” to show possession for people and things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Linguapress](https://linguapress.com/grammar/possessives.htm#:%7E:text=Possessive%20structures%20in%20English%20%2D%20use,with%20people%22%20is%20quite%20wrong.):

> The commonly repeated "rule" that you can "only use 's with people" is
> quite wrong. It is a very broad generalisation, and there are  lots of
> excep­tions.

In cases of real possession, where someone possesses an object, **'s** is most common. For example:

> Mary's dress was very pretty. (correct)
>
> The dress of Mary was very pretty. (wrong)

When a real person possesses a quality, attribute or action, **'s** is probably more common, but you can often use either. When you use **'s**, it emphasizes the possessor. When you use **of**, it emphasizes the quality or attribute. For example:

> The Queen's reputation is remarkable. (emphasizes the Queen)
>
> The reputation of the Queen is remarkable. (emphasizes the reputation)

However, the more intangible the possessor, the more common **of** is used. For example:

> The cost of a ticket was outrageous. (correct)
>
> The ticket's cost was outrageous. (very awkward)

> The rear bumper of the car was damaged. (probably more common)
>
> The car's rear bumper was damaged. (perfectly fine)

You must use **of** when you express that something is a part or proportion of a whole or the unit of a group:

> A majority of the people prefer the incumbent.

> The rest of the cake was left uneaten.

> The top of the mountain is in the clouds.

> The collection of paintings is astonishing.

There are a lot of rules and many exceptions. I'm afraid that sometimes it comes down to how it sounds and the structure of the sentence.

There's no reason not to use **'s** to indicate **possession** in an essay of any type. You might be thinking of a convention with **contractions**, where you might avoid using contractions in essays because they are too informal:

> We discovered that a student cannot learn as quickly if he is hungry. (more formal)
>
> We discovered that a student can't learn as quickly if he's hungry. (informal)

Comment: Thanks very much,that’s a very detailed answer. 
However I am a bit confused when I was reading about the “intangible possessor”part, “ the more intangible the possessor, the more common of is used”,but a ticket is a tangible thing,why is the use of “s”awkward here?              Thanks again for answering my question.

Comment: That's an interesting question, @Albus. I would say that nowadays a ticket is less and less tangible. While we sometimes mean a physical piece of paper or card, we usually mean the permission to enter or make use of some facility, which can be represented by a physical object but might be embodied in an email or just mean the presence of our name on a list.

Comment: I should probably use a better example, such as "The value of an idea." I will add that to the answer.